# How to migrate spring (no boot) + vaadin to tomcat 10

Tags: spring, tomcat, vaadin

I'm trying to migrate spring (no boot) legacy project to tomcat 10.
currently pom.xml for the project is looking:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>4.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.internal-jar</groupId>
    <artifactId>internal-jar-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>internal-jar::internal-jar-war</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <jacoco.skip>true</jacoco.skip>


        <internal.jar.java.source.version>17</internal.jar.java.source.version>
        <internal.jar.java.target.version>17</internal.jar.java.target.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <commons-io.version>2.7</commons-io.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.7</joda-time.version>
        <log4j.version>2.17.1</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>6.0.9</spring.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.23.0</vaadin.version>
        <fasterxml.jackson.version>2.16.1</fasterxml.jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mycompany -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.internal-jar</groupId>
            <artifactId>internal-jar</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
            <version>24.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- So transacted channels work -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required to override tetris "provided" scope -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- So Spring logs through LOG4J2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Apache Commons overrides required by Spring -->
        <!-- Required to override tetris root version and "provided" scope -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required to override tetris root "provided" scope -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For JavaMelody monitoring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.56.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>internal-jar</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>-->
                   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>-->
                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${internal.jar.java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${internal.jar.java.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>publish</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactory>
                                <includeEnvVars>true</includeEnvVars>
                                <envVarsExcludePatterns>*password*,*secret*,*key*,*token*,*passphrase*</envVarsExcludePatterns>
                                <timeoutSec>60</timeoutSec>
                            </artifactory>
                            <publisher>
                                <contextUrl>https://mycompanyavm.jfrog.io/artifactory</contextUrl>
                                <username>${artifactory.user}</username>
                                <password>${artifactory.password}</password>
                                <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                                <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                                <publishBuildInfo>false</publishBuildInfo>
                            </publisher>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/binary/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/binary/**</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

</project>
```

when i'm trying to deploy the war file to tomcat 10 i'm receiving several exceptions which i'm not able to recognize:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application Lookup instance is not found in VaadinContext. The instance is supposed to be created by a ServletContainerInitializer. Issues known to cause this problem are:
- A Spring Boot application deployed as a war-file but the main application class does not extend SpringBootServletInitializer
- An embedded server that is not set up to execute ServletContainerInitializers
- Unit tests which do not properly set up the context for the test

    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:53)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.get(ApplicationConfiguration.java:47)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createPropertyDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:73)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer$StubServletConfig.createDeploymentConfiguration(ServletDeployer.java:139)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.lambda$getServletConfigurations$0(ServletDeployer.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.getServletConfigurations(ServletDeployer.java:197)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.contextInitialized(ServletDeployer.java:148)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4438)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4876)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1833)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
```

then in logs i see next one:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [transactionalNonGroupChannel] with key 'transactionalNonGroupChannel'
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.lambda$registerBeans$2(MBeanExporter.java:552)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:552)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:394)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4876)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1833)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExportException: Could not create ModelMBean for managed resource [transactionalNonGroupChannel] with key 'transactionalNonGroupChannel'
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.createAndConfigureMBean(MBeanExporter.java:825)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:678)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler does not support JDK dynamic proxies - export the target beans directly or use CGLIB proxies instead
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler.checkManagedBean(MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.AbstractMBeanInfoAssembler.getMBeanInfo(AbstractMBeanInfoAssembler.java:64)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.getMBeanInfo(MBeanExporter.java:847)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.createAndConfigureMBean(MBeanExporter.java:820)
    ... 58 more
```

finally i have one more stack trace in terminal

```
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
24-Jan-2024 16:54:31.787 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [internal-jar-war] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
24-Jan-2024 16:54:31.789 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [internal-jar-war] appears to have started a thread named [Catalina-utility-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5231)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1301)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1283)
 java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
 java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:305)
 java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
 java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
 java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
 java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
[2024-01-24 04:54:31,825] Artifact internal-jar-war:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

UPD:
i have made following changes into my pom.xml:

1. Raised vaadin version.

```
<vaadin.version>24.3.3</vaadin.version>
```

2. Added vaadin dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

3. Removed all the others vaadin dependencies except vaadin-spring.

When i did this the code failed to compile because of absence of some vaadin classes for example:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
import com.vaadin.ui.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification.Type;
```

so i added following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

so i was able to build the application.
But when i'm deploying the application in addtion to previous exceptions i see new one in logs:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeStartupListener]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

the stack trace appears between second and third traces of original description.

UPD1: I have done migration to vaadin 24, but my application not starts - none of previously listed exceptions appears in logs, now i have following:
`30-Jan-2024 17:06:13.894 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file` and  `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5231) org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1301) org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305) org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305) org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1283) java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:305) java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java) java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)`

Comment: Are you sure that all your components work well with jakarta.servlet as opposed to javax.servlet? Especially Vaadin 8 I'd have an eye on - if I'm not mistaken it's quite old and I'd be surprised if it was already compatible.

Comment: You need Vaadin 24 to deploy it on Tomcat 10.

Comment: Your update doesn't make it better. You need to remove the compatibility server and migrate for real. That package is not meant for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Switch to Vaadin 24, which will be a significant change due to major changes in the framework - it'll be a full migration project.
2. Get Vaadin 8 Extended Maintenance, and the new vaadin-spring release that supports Spring 6, Java 17 and all that stuff. The first beta was just released, so you might need to wait for some time for it to become stable. This also requires a commercial subscription.