# Tomcat 10 not seeing log providers

Tags: tomcat, logging

i have tomcat 10 to deploy my web app - spring (no boot) application, i'm deploying it using intellij idea and tomcat 10.1.18, now what i'm seeing in server logs:

```
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J(W): Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J(W): Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/IvanKarotki/Program_Files/apache-tomcat-10.1.18/webapps/opera-agent-war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.22.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

while in pom.xml i have following:

```
 <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomcat-slf4j-logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat10-slf4j-logback</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--         Required to override tetris "provided" scope -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--         So Spring logs through LOG4J2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j2-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and

```
        <log4j.version>2.22.1</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>2.0.11</slf4j.version>
```

tomcat/webapps/myapp/web-inf/lib contains all the jar-files.

So could someone explain, please, why tomcat reporting that no providers found, but then something is ignored? So are providers missed or ignored? And how to configure full logging locally, because i couldn't start my application and see no reason why.

Actually what i'm struggling is [How to migrate spring (no boot) + vaadin to tomcat 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77875310/how-to-migrate-spring-no-boot-vaadin-to-tomcat-10/77899729#77899729). I have migrated my application to java 17 and tomcat 10 compatibility and still failing to run it, without visible reason.